# BASH doesn't like my regex

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I'm trying to get the 2-digit month and 2-digit year a file was modified, but's it's not working..

```
modified=$(stat -c %y "$line"); 
# modified="2018-08-22 14:39:36.400469308 -0400"
if [[ $modified =~ ".{2}(\d{2})-(\d{2})" ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]
fi
```

- Bash demo: http://rextester.com/DJSPH52792
- RegEx demo: https://regex101.com/r/UEOlMO/1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's not working about it? If this question matches exactly what you're trying in `bash`, the issue is you're missing a closing brace `}` at the end of the second-to-last line of your script.

Comment: FYI, you *could* use the `date` command to convert a `stat` output of a UNIX timestamp into the exact date portion you want.

Comment: this question appears to be a request for how to implement a ```[ . -nt .[.] ]``` test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the quotes suppress the meaning of the special characters in the regex ([online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b)):

> An additional binary operator, `=~`, is available, ... Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string. ... If you want to match a character that’s special to the regular expression grammar, it has to be quoted to remove its special meaning.

The manual goes on to recommend putting the regex in a variable to prevent some clashes between the shell parsing and the regex syntax.

Second, `\d` doesn't do what you think it does, but just matches a literal `d`.

Also note that `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` contains the whole matching string, and indexes `1` and up contain the captured groups.

I'd also strongly suggest using four-digit years, so:

```
modified=$(stat -c %y "$file")
re='^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})'
if [[ $modified =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "year:  ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "month: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
else
    echo "invalid timestamp"
fi
```

For a file modified today, that gives `year: 2018` and `month: 08`. Note that numbers with a leading zero will be considered octal by the shell and possibly other utilities.

(Four-digit years have less issues if you ever need to handles dates from the 1900's, and they're easier to recognize as years and not days of month.)

Comment: Note that changed in 3.2, you can also use `shopt -s compat31` or `BASH_COMPAT=3.1` for `[[ $modified =~ ".{2}([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})" ]]` to work.

Comment: pretty bold suggesting that I use data other than what I said I needed without having even the slightest clue what I needed it for, but other than that this makes a lot of sense. thank you for your time. I'll mark it as the answer as soon as I have a chance to try it out in the morning.

Answer (score 4):

Don't need regular expressions for this:

```
$ touch -t 197001010000 myfile
$ ls -l myfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 Jan  1  1970 myfile
$ IFS='-' read -r year month _rest < <(stat -c %y myfile)
$ echo "$year:${year#??}"$month"
1970:70:01
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, with GNU `date`, you can do:

```
eval "$(date -r "$file" +'year=%Y month=%-m day=%-d')"
```

To have the modification time's year, month and day component stored in `$year`, `$month` and `$day` respectively (as decimal integers, remove the `-`s in `%-m` and `%-d` if you care for the leading zeros; see also `%y` for 2-digit years).

(note that contrary to GNU `stat`, for files of type symlink, the modification time of the target of the symlink is considered rather than that of the symlink itself. With GNU `stat`, you'd use `stat -L`).